# Hyperledger Composer on a local network of Ubuntu servers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I was able to setup Hyperledger Composer on Docker containers on a mac by following the instructions here: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html. I was also able to develop a proof of concept project with both a mobile web app that connected the blockchain via a rest API.

Now, I am trying to run the nodes on actual Ubuntu servers in a local network but I can't seem to find any tutorial to explains how to do that.

I know I might have some gap in my knowledge of computer architecture or networking in general that's why I am struggling with this.

I was looking at the `downloadFabric.sh` script in `fabric-tools` and I see how the Docker images are filled. I was thinking maybe I should just pull the Docker images to the individual Linux servers.

`### Pull and tag the latest Hyperledger Fabric base image.`

`docker pull hyperledger/fabric-peer:$ARCH-1.0.1` on server 1

`docker pull hyperledger/fabric-ca:$ARCH-1.0.1` on server 2

`docker pull hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:$ARCH-1.0.1` on server 3

`docker pull hyperledger/fabric-orderer:$ARCH-1.0.1`

`docker pull hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:$ARCH-1.0.1`

and so on.

Please, how will you do this? Are there any resources I missed while researching how to do this? Can you point me to some resources that I can read to help understand how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

So Hyperledger Composer will connect to the Fabric that you configure. So your problem is to configure a Fabric environment and set of nodes, using the host name resolution etc that you want to configure your network.

Would advise to check out the Fabric Docs http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html to build your network. They have some sample-networks (see the Github Repository here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/release/examples )

The 'Fabric' that is set up by Hyperledger Composer's dev environment is just a Dev environment with one peer configured (via docker containers) to get you going.

You need to understand from the Fabric Docs how to set up your network, then come back to Composer (once all that is set up) and use connection profiles to connect to the runtime Fabric.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using `docker-composer` which builds on the docker client and makes it easier to run multiple docker containers. Please consult the [manual](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) to install docker-compose.

After installing docker-compose, you can use the `startFabric.sh` script provided [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html) to start Fabric containers you had downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider deploying Fabric with it's sister project Hyperledger Cello. Specifically, the [Ansible driver](https://github.com/hyperledger/cello/tree/master/src/agent/ansible) for Kubernetes.

The samples provided in both Composer and Fabric are mostly for single host deployment. You could adapt the Docker Compose to use Swarm, but even Docker is [moving away](https://venturebeat.com/2017/10/17/docker-embraces-kubernetes-will-let-customers-run-it-alongside-swarm/) from Swarm, now.

Of course, if you just want to try to run locally, then the [Build Your First Network](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html) tutorial in Hyperledger Fabric will get you rolling with the docker images in your question.